# Trouble sorting by last name all data pulled from a Query

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Below is my query.  I am pulling all data columns from all sheets.  I want to sort by last name (Col7 or F).

```
=query({'REGION 10 (Closed)'!B5:CN;'REGION 10 (Active)'!B9:CN;'REGION 9 (Closed)'!B5:CN;'REGION 9 (Active)'!B9:CN;'REGION 8 (Closed)'!B5:CN;'REGION 8 (Active)'!B9:CN;'REGION 7 (Closed)'!B5:CN;'REGION 7 (Active)'!B9:CN;'REGION 6 (Closed)'!B5:CN;'REGION 6 (Active)'!B9:CN;'REGION 5 (Closed)'!B5:CN;'REGION 5 (Active)'!B9:CN;'REGION 4 (Closed)'!B5:CN;'REGION 4 (Active)'!B9:CN;'REGION 3 (Closed)'!B5:CN;'REGION 3 (Active)'!B9:CN;'REGION 2 (Closed)'!B5:CN;'REGION 2 (Active)'!B9:CN;'REGION 1 (Closed)'!B5:CN;'REGION 1 (Active)'!B9:CN;'REGION National
 (Closed)'!B5:CN},"select * where Col7 is not Null")
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what edits were made.  I am asking for best way to include a sort on last name field (which all sheets have). This is my first attempt at this type of formula

Answer (score 0):

F = Col5 in B:CN range:

```
=QUERY({
 'REGION 10 (Closed)'!B5:CN; 'REGION 10 (Active)'!B9:CN;
 'REGION 9 (Closed)'!B5:CN;  'REGION 9 (Active)'!B9:CN;
 'REGION 8 (Closed)'!B5:CN;  'REGION 8 (Active)'!B9:CN;
 'REGION 7 (Closed)'!B5:CN;  'REGION 7 (Active)'!B9:CN;
 'REGION 6 (Closed)'!B5:CN;  'REGION 6 (Active)'!B9:CN;
 'REGION 5 (Closed)'!B5:CN;  'REGION 5 (Active)'!B9:CN;
 'REGION 4 (Closed)'!B5:CN;  'REGION 4 (Active)'!B9:CN;
 'REGION 3 (Closed)'!B5:CN;  'REGION 3 (Active)'!B9:CN;
 'REGION 2 (Closed)'!B5:CN;  'REGION 2 (Active)'!B9:CN;
 'REGION 1 (Closed)'!B5:CN;  'REGION 1 (Active)'!B9:CN;
 'REGION National (Closed)'!B5:CN},
 "where Col7 is not null order by Col5 asc")
```

or `desc` if you want